# Add values to unexisting keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, keyerror

I have a directory with many pickled files, each containing a dictionary. The filename indicates the setting of the dictionary. E.g.: `20NewsGroup___10___Norm-False___Probs-True___euclidean.pickle`.

I want to combine these different dicts all in one large dict. To do this, I have written the following code:

```
PATH = '<SOME PATH>'
all_dicts = os.listdir(PATH)

one_dict = dict()

for i, filename in enumerate(all_dicts):
    infile = open(PATH+filename, 'rb')
    new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    splitted = filename.split('___')
    splitted[4] = splitted[4].split('.')[0]
    one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]][splitted[4]] = new_dict
```

However, when I run this, I get a `KeyError`, as the key for `splitted[0]` does not yet exist. What is the best way to populate a dictionary similar to what I envision?

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864702/python-load-multiple-pickle-objects-into-a-single-dictionary
you can iterate dir files and combine

Comment: Thanks Shiva, with the answer in this post the setting information gets lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create in these fields

Example:

```py
from typing import List

PATH = '<SOME PATH>'
all_dicts = os.listdir(PATH)

def check_exist_path(target_dict, paths: List[str]):
     for key in paths:
          if key not in target_dict:
               target_dict[key] = {}

          target_dict = target_dict[key]

one_dict = dict()

for i, filename in enumerate(all_dicts):
    infile = open(PATH+filename, 'rb')
    new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    splitted = filename.split('___')
    splitted[4] = splitted[4].split('.')[0]

    for i in range(5):
        check_exist_path(one_dict, [splitted[j] for j in range(i)])

    one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]][splitted[4]] = new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use try-except blocks:

```
for i, filename in enumerate(all_dicts):
    infile = open(PATH+filename, 'rb')
    new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    splitted = filename.split('___')
    splitted[4] = splitted[4].split('.')[0]
    try:
        one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]][splitted[4]] = new_dict
    except KeyError:
        one_dict[splitted[0]] = {}
        one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]] = {}
        one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]] = {}
        one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]] = {}
        one_dict[splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]][splitted[4]] = new_dict
```

This code tries to access nested dictionary keys, if they don't exist, then the code will create them with an empty dictionary.

Comment: Please, check your solution for `all_dicts = {"20NewsGroup___10___Norm-False___Probs-True___euclidean.pickle",   "20NewsGroup___20___Norm-False___Probs-True___euclidean.pickle"}`